# jQuery selectors not working or unable to bind events

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several dynamically created links and forms on one page named with IDs `sub_comment_form_[id]` and `sub_add_comment_[id]`, respectively. I'm trying to:

1. Hide all forms when the page loads
2. Bind a click event to the link directly above the form to hide/show the form.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my *selectors*, or if jQuery simply does not allow *binding on multiple objects at once*. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="sub_add_comment_to_answer_[id]">Add comment</a>
<form id="sub_comment_form_to_answer_[id]"...
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form[ @id^='sub_comment_form' ]").hide();

$("a[ @id^='sub_add_comment' ]").click(function() {
  var sibform = $(this).next("form");

  if (sibform.is(':hidden')) {
    $(this).text('Cancel');
    sibform.slideDown('fast');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Add comment');
    sibform.slideUp('fast');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you to @Nick and @BigRossLabs. I've edited the question to remove the typo and make the root problem of the missing '@' clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of jQuery (1.3+) there's no `@` on attribute selectors anymore, it just looks like this:

```
$("form[id^='sub_comment_form']").hide();
//and..
$("a[id^='sub_add_comment']").click(function() {
```

This first one was also missing a closing brace, so be sure to fix that too :)

Also, be sure both of these are wrapped in a `document.ready` handler so they execute after the DOM is ready, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("form[id^='sub_comment_form']").hide();
  $("a[id^='sub_add_comment']").click(function() { ... });
});
```

---

Alternatively, instead of these ID starts-with selectors you could use a class, for instance:

```
<a href="#" class="addComment">Add comment</a>
```

And bind it like this:

```
  $("a.addComment").click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Line 1 is missing the closing ']' so it should be...

```
$("form[@id^='sub_comment_form']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also a good practice to prefix variables containing jQuery objects with a $.

```
var $sibform = $(this).next("form");
```

This way you always know when you're dealing with a jQuery object and not. And thereby keeps you from binding a jQuery object in itself.